# C-shell syntax: Too many ('s. warning in .cshrc

Tags: shell, csh

Is the problem in the `PATH` section? 
When I try to fix the `PATH` with `setenv` I then get:

```
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

Here is a snip of the file:

```
setenv MAIL /usr/spool/mail/$USER
setenv MATLABPATH /home/users/me/matlab/functions:/home/users/me/matlab/scripts
setenv PYTHONPATH /home/users/me/python/modules:/home/users/me/python/scripts
set path=( /sbin /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/java/bin
           /usr/bin/X11 ~/bin)
if (! $?csh) then
   if($?prompt) then
        set prmptchr=$prompt
   else
        set prmptchr="/"
   endif
   alias setprompt 'set prompt = "$cwd$prmptchr "' # directory name in prompt
   alias cd 'chdir \!*; setprompt'
   alias pushd 'pushd \!*; setprompt'
   alias popd 'popd \!*; setprompt'
   setprompt
endif
```

Comment: yes, problem is in the `path` section. It should be either all on one line, or you need to use the continutation character at the end of any unterminated line. i.e. `.... /usr/local/java/bin \\` . Not really a  programming Q, in the future please post such queries on http://superuser.com . AND Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter sorry about that I'll keep it in mind. Now I get this:
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
`set path=(/sbin /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/java/bin  
/usr/bin/X11 ~/bin)
if (! $?csh) then  
   if($?prompt) then  
        set prmptchr=$prompt  
   else  
        set prmptchr="/"  
   endif  
   alias setprompt 'set prompt = "$cwd$prmptchr "' # directory name in  
 prompt
   alias cd 'chdir \!*; setprompt'  
   alias pushd 'pushd \!*; setprompt'  
   alias popd 'popd \!*; setprompt'  
   setprompt`

Comment: Is all on one line the only change you've made? When I copy/paste your code into my `csh`, it all works. Sorry, busy today, will check back when I have time. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 2 issues corrected:

```
setenv MAIL /usr/spool/mail/$USER
setenv MATLABPATH /home/users/me/matlab/functions:/home/users/me/matlab/scripts 
setenv PYTHONPATH /home/users/me/python/modules:/home/users/me/python/scripts

# Added \ to split across multiple lines
set path=( /sbin /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/java/bin \
           /usr/bin/X11 ~/bin)
if (! $?csh) then
   if($?prompt) then
        # Added " around $prompt to make sure it's quoted correctly.
        set prmptchr="$prompt"
   else
        set prmptchr="/"
   endif
   alias setprompt 'set prompt = "$cwd$prmptchr "' # directory name in prompt
   alias cd 'chdir \!*; setprompt'
   alias pushd 'pushd \!*; setprompt'
   alias popd 'popd \!*; setprompt'
   setprompt
endif
```

Comment: besides the continuation char for `path ..` what is the other change? I can't see it, and as I mentioned, when I pasted your original code (with `path =` all on one line), it worked. Glad you found a solution. If you didn't know, you can accept your own soluton as an answer and gain valuable reputation points. Good luck and keep posting.

Comment: @shellter Quotes in `set prmptchr="$prompt"`